# Implementation with gcloud deploy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, gcloud, webdeploy

I currently have an application with Angular in an app engine in GCP.
After an update in the application we try to deploy with the command `gcloud app deploy`, which gives us the following error:

```
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] The following errors occurred while copying files to App Engine:
BCID verification is required when deploy to an app with a PROD_PROFILE.
```

Previously we have worked without any problem.
What could be the error?

I add that I previously performed these steps

- `gcloud auth login`
- `gcloud config set project ...`
- `gcloud init`
- `gcloud app deploy`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHci0.png)

Comment: Is that the exact error that gcloud gives you? Because the grammatical error in it makes me doubt that. In any case based on the fact that there seem to be no mention of any of those things in the app engine docs, but only in posts about internal security that sounds more like a (hopefully temporary) issue, did you try to run the deploy command again after waiting a bit?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I just attached the image in case I didn't copy the error right.
Yes, I tried again after a few days and got the same error several times.